# Command block set spawn

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do I set spawn point using command block with coordinates 8,462 4,00000 8,591?I have been trying, but haven't been able to do it right.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what exactly you've tried?

Comment: y=400000 is far above the world max height. The spawnpoint has to be inside your world.

Comment: What did you try

Comment: Please provide me with more information.

Answer (score 2):

This is the syntax:

```
/spawnpoint [player] [<x> <y> <z>]
```

With your example, it'd be something like:

```
/spawnpoint 8.462 4.00000 8.591
```

As stated by @XeroOl, decimals might not work here this way. If so, try replacing , (comma) with . (dots).

You can also just get to the location of it and type

```
/spawnpoint
```

That will set it to the exact position where you are.

[Source](https://www.digminecraft.com/game_commands/spawnpoint_command.php)

Comment: The /spawnpoint command might not like commas or decimals in the inputs

Comment: @XeroOl true, I can not be sure though as I found this on the wiki, not my personal knowledge. *Adding notation to my answer*

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment yet as I'm lacking reputation, but as I look at this after doing a heavy amount of typing, I think this deserves its own answer.

While Alex answered it well, they actually has a few problems in their first example:

- They forgot to mention that the player **must** be specified if using a command block.
- When using coordinates in commands, you cannot use a thousands separator. Fixing it, their example should be instead:
  `/spawnpoint 8462 400000 8591`
  but still, that high Y coordinate.. might not work...
  **EDIT:** This was clarified to me that the period that the Alex was using was probably for the decimal part of the location. Still won't work as I edited it, but my apologizes anyways.
- You cannot place a spawn point where your feet would be in a block. Doesn't matter if it is a lower slab, grass or plant (any), or even a pressure plate.

So to further follow up on the command... if a player invoked it,

```
/spawnpoint [<player>] [<x> <y> <z>]
```

and if a command block invoked it,

```
spawnpoint <player> <x> <y> <z>
```

To have a pressure plate with a command block work to set it to that exact location, I'll post an example vertical slice layout here (with a command).

```
X
X
_
C
```

The `X` represents an air block, `_` for the pressure plate, and `C` for the command block. Any other layout can work as long as you update the coordinates to work. You **need** to have actual air blocks to have it as a valid spawn point, two air blocks (as the player is 2 blocks tall by default), and always needing specify the foot location's coordinate when entering the spawn point.

I'm going to have it so just anyone within a 3 block radius of the target location to have their spawn point set (so it works better in multi-player custom adventure / puzzle maps). I'll also specify why I'm using the values I am using just for being helpful.

If, for example, your command block was at the coordinates (125,83,2568), this is what you would probably put in.

```
spawnpoint @a[x=125,y=85,z=2568,r=3] ~ ~2 ~
```

Within a command block, the opening `/` is normally ignored by the game.

First part:

- `@a` - specifies all users, but we limit with the selector part within square brackets `[]`
- `x=nnn`, `y=nnn` and `z=nnn` - specifies where we are doing the *center* of our search at.
  **Note:** you *must* put the exact coordinates in as using the *relative* coordinate feature (`~`) does not work in a selector!
- `r=3` - specifies anyone at maximum 3 blocks away from the specified center will be affected, otherwise the `@a` will still affect everyone (*I haven't tested. Can anyone confirm if this is true or if it instead would require the player to be on that exact spot?*).

Second part just specifies where the command block will set the spawn point for the targeted player(s) (specified as `x y z`, in that order). `~` means use that coordinate relative to who / what invoked it (for us in this instance, the command block; gets more complicated if chaining with that one command, which would be where the last command was invoked) in the specified value. Pretending `N` is a number without commas or periods, `~-N` would be for that coordinate minus `N` (further into the negative values), and for instead adding to the coordinate, `~N`.

Finally, I must note that if you are using a non-vanilla server, you should look up how it works. Sometimes custom ones may use stuff like `/tp` as exact coordinates instead of centering on a block. Yes, odd, but it has existed in what I experienced.

Comment: `"When using coordinates in commands, you cannot use a thousands separator"`; it was more likely to be decimal notation (which [differs based on location](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Examples_of_use)), not a thousands separator. The command won't work as it is due to the Y value. `"x=~"`; you cannot use relative coordinates in selectors.

Comment: @Skylinerw I forgot all about that... serves me right for being away from Minecraft for so long. *\*facepalm\**

Comment: @Skylinerw let me know if this edit needs... another edit.

Answer (score 0):

The command your missing is the **/set.** and your missing the name.

> set @p spawnpoint [x] [y] [z]

@p represents the nearest player which is usually the player on the pressure plate. I hope that's fixes your problem! Please comment back if you need any more help.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it. I would suggest the first one for singleplayer mode. The first one uses `/setworldspawn`
The syntax is:

```
/setworldspawn [x y z]
```

Just replace `[x y z]` with your values. This sets the default spawn location for all players to the given coordinates. The second way is better on multiplayer servers. It is `/spawnpoint`. The syntax for this is:

```
/spawnpoint [player] [x y z]
```

This sets the spawn location of only that player to the given coordinates. Replace`[player]`with your player name and replace `[x y z]` with the desired coordinates. Hoped this helps.